# Algorithm to find if a square is removable from a group of squares without disconnection

Tags: algorithms, geometry

I have a group of squares on a 2d grid, here's an example

[image: grid with group of squares]

I need an algorithm to find out whether we are able to remove a square while keeping the entire group connected. Below is an image where I colored squares that are possible to remove in green, and squares that would make the group disconnected if removed in red.

[image: group of squares colored by ability to remove with group staying connected]

My current method is to remove the square from the group, and run a flood fill algorithm starting from an arbitrary square to see whether the group is connected or not. If the number of squares retrieved from the flood fill is less than the total number of squares for the group, we know that the group is not connected, in 2+ pieces. This is not very performant and it is better to be able to know whether a square is removable before actually removing it.

I noticed that we can tell whether the square is removable by just its surrounding 8 squares. **Edit:** As @KilianFoth pointed out in a comment, this is not always true. However, in my case I can ensure that there is no longer path connecting figure 1 for example.

Here are several examples, centered on the square in question.

[image: 6 examples of 3x3 grids showing whether the middle square is removable]

I can create a list of booleans representing whether each surrounding square is in the group. It could be in the form `[north, ne, e, se, s, sw, w, nw]` going clockwise around, so number 6 on the image above would be `[False, True, True, False, False, False, True, True]`. I need a function/algorithm that can take in one of these lists, and output whether the square is removable or not. Here are examples from the above images.

```
[True, False, False, False, False, False, True, False] -> False (not removable)
[True, False, False, False, False, False, True, True] -> True (removable)
[True, False, True, False, False, False, True, True] -> False
[True, True, True, False, False, False, True, True] -> True
[True, True, True, False, True, False, True, True] -> False
[False, True, True, False, False, False, True, True] -> False
```

If it works better, the bools can be variables like `north` or `southeast`.

My first thought was to check the cardinal directions, and if there are only two squares in our group, then it isn't removable. This works for examples 1, 4, and 6, but gets 2, 3 and 5 wrong. I know the algorithm needs to take diagonals into account, because 1 and 2 are the same only including cardinal directions.

How can I make an algorithm that tells me whether or not a square is removable from the group without causing disconnection?

Comment: "I noticed that we can tell whether the square is removable by just its surrounding 8 squares." - Your premise is wrong. The local context only defines a *sufficient* condition, not a *necessary* one. The squares that seemingly become disconnected e.g. in figure 1 might still be connected via a longer path.

Comment: @KilianFoth While this is true for what I wrote, in my case I can ensure that figure 1 is not connected by a longer path. If they were connected by a longer path, there would be a hole in the middle, and since my grid is tiled several groups of the same size, this would not be possible (size of hole < size of group). I should've included this in the question though thank you.

Comment: Since your examples show that diagonal connections don’t count I fail to see why you count the surrounding squares as 8. It’s seems there are only 4. Please define “connected” clearly.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003032/how-to-modify-dijkstra-algorithm-to-find-all-possible-paths) you might be able to use part of what is shown in the question and the answer from this SO question. Basically, take dijkstra's algorithm and perform a breadth first search that each "left over" square has a path to each other.

Comment: @candied_orange Yes, diagonal squares don't count as touching. The reason I included all 8 surrounding squares is, figure 1 becomes disconnected after removing the middle square, so the middle square is not removable. Figure 2's square **is** removable because the rest of the squares would still be conected if you remove the middle square. Figure 1 and 2 are identical if you don't include diagonals

Comment: @eparham7861 This doesn't seem that much more efficient than my flood fill check of if the group is connected after removing the square. My goal is to find if removing the square would cause disconnection without checking the whole group. Maybe dikstra's can be modified to just check only the surrounding 8 though.

Comment: @Evan I think you’ll find that all you have to check is that the 4 surrounding squares remain connected to each other. Because if the are then the removed square was not needed to connect them. That is to say, if removing a square causes a disconnection it must cause that disconnection with some of those 4. Therefore you don’t need to prove connection beyond those 4. That may simplify the algorithms you’d use here.

Comment: To me, this smells like NP because whether or not a square can be removed depends on the state of all the other squares and after a square has been removed, the state of all the other squares *might* have changed and the sequence of removal matters (removing a square might needlessly isolate a square that could otherwise have been removed first). The possible orderings of `n` squares is `n!`. Of course it's just an intuition.

Comment: @benrudgers and here I was thinking we were going simply consider one square at a time.

Comment: If you just need to find one square, it's a lot simpler. Just pick one with 0 or 1 connections.  If it matters which square is chosen (there are values stored at each node in the graph) then there are missing criteria. But unless it makes a difference which square is removed, then calculating the entire graph after a removable square is found is might be wasted work because a removable square in iteration one might not be removable in iteration two and likewise a "critical" square in iteration one might not be a "critical" square in iteration two.

Comment: @benrudgers no. I think it’s more like we’re expected to return removable, true or false, given a graph and a square.

Comment: You wrote *"However, in my case I can ensure that there is no longer path connecting figure 1 for example"* - so you want to solve a different problem than the one described initially, but you missed to tell us precisely what you mean by "your case",  Sorry, the problem statement is not clear from what you wrote. In case you mean you want to detect "disconnections by removals" in a 3x3 rectangle: that's trivial. This won't guarantee to be disconnections in any kind of bigger area, however, as you have been told. Voting to close as "unclear".

Comment: What Evan described (just looking at 8 neighbors) provides a heuristic, but it is not a 100% correct one. In other words, it is a heuristic that is incorrect by itself, but has the potential of speeding up algorithm search when combined with another (slower) heuristic that is 100% correct.

Comment: I believe Evan's question belongs to the knowledge domain of **digital image processing**. In case this question is closed for being unclear (or, an inability to ask the question clearly), I would suggest Evan talk to friends and classmates who have taken the digital image processing course, who will be able to give the correct answer very quickly.

Comment: @DocBrown Yes, I should have been more clear in my question about condition that there cannot be holes. My emphasis was on performance because I already have a working algorithm, as I stated. My solution to the problem using 3x3 neighborhoods is way more efficient than other solutions that check the whole group. I can edit the no holes requirement into my question. No need to close it :)

Comment: @Evan: so the group of squares is guaranteed not to contain any holes before the removal, and you want to take advantage of it - is it that what you mean? Do you want the "no holes" constraint to persist after the removal? Your current examples do not show what is expected here.

Comment: @Evan to expand on the comment I provided, you could take the surrounding squares of the target square to check and check that the surrounding squares have a path to each other without the target square. With candied_orange's suggestion, I think it would have a max of 4 checks at a time. You could also put in a short circuit if the target square has only 1 surrounding square, if that's valid.

Answer (score 0):

With help from a few comments, I realized that all I have to do was check to see if the surrounding squares are touching each other. I noticed a pattern with my bool lists above - if there is more than one chain/streak of `True`'s (including carrying over between start and end of the list), then removing the square will cause a disconnected group. If there is more than one streak of `True`'s, (checked by `longest_true_chain != num_trues`), then the surrounding squares are not connected and the square is not removable.

Here is my python code

```py
def removable(bool_list):
    num_trues = bool_list.count(True)
    longest_true_chain = 0
    current_true_chain = 0
    for b in bool_list*2:  # use *2 to include streaks carrying across nw to n (end to beginning of list)
        if b:
            current_true_chain += 1
        else:
            longest_true_chain = max(longest_true_chain, current_true_chain)
            current_true_chain = 0
    longest_true_chain = max(longest_true_chain, current_true_chain)
    return longest_true_chain >= num_trues
```

Comment: Code doesn't seem to work with all true s

Comment: @RiaD Thanks I modified the last 2 lines and it should now.

Comment: I think this approach only works, if you group of squares does not contain holes. If it is allowed to contain holes, you cannot decide connectivity by just looking at the local neighborhood.

Answer (score 0):

Idea #1

Apply morphological erosion repeatedly. After each step, count the number of connected components, and compare with the number from the previous step.

If the number of connected components have changed, a new disconnection has occurred. When that is detected, perform a more detailed check of each of the squares that were removed in the most recent round of morphological erosion, to find out which one(s) caused the disconnection.

This can be combined with all other approaches mentioned in other answers.

The benefit of using morphological erosion is that it is a "batch processing", i.e. it can remove a large number of squares in each step, as long as disconnection has not happened. Once a disconnection happened, though, a more detailed check is needed.

---

Idea #2

Random network flow check.

Randomly pick some pairs of squares. For each pair of squares, compute their path. On a new map, increment the score of each square along the path. Repeat.

If there are "bottlenecks", namely squares that appear to be quite essential to the connection between random pairs of squares, it might be the case that removing a square from these bottlenecks may cause a disconnection. However, this is not a failproof approach. It is a heuristics that sometimes give wrong result.

Answer (score -1):

Consider a graph where vertices are squares and they are connected by an edge if the squares are connected on the grid. Then you need to find vertices which you can delete without losing connectivity. They are exactly all vertices except [cut vertices](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component) by definition. There's a well known algorithm to find all cut vertices which is basically one DFS. It's described on the same wiki page.

Comment: This is a solution for finding *all* of the potential removable squares in an efficient manner, not just testing one. Not sure if that is what the OP meant.